# CUDA Programming with Thrust Library Radix Sort

Tags: sorting, cuda, thrust, radix

Newbie on Thrust - in my VS2010 C++ program, I have working fine:

```
#include <thrust/sort.h>
thrust :: stable_sort_by_key (sortkey , sortkey + nmu, indexes );
```

But now I want to use thrust :: stable_radix_sort_key.  I've added the include -

```
#include <thrust/detail/device/cuda/detail/stable_radix_sort.h>
```

but VS can't find `"thrust :: stable_radix_sort_key ( ...)"`

I think the associated header files are not being found in their directories?
What's wrong.  Does anyone have some example code for calling this thrust library routine?

Thanks.

Comment: Please indent your code lines 4 spaces to avoid stackoverflow formatting `#include` as a title.

Answer (score 3):

`thrust::stable_radix_sort_key()` is not part of the thrust public interface.  You should use `thrust::stable_sort_by_key()`.

If the keys you are sorting by are of a plain-old data type comparable with operator< (such as int, float, etc.), then I believe Thrust will use the radix sort internally.

Also, I don't think you should `#include <thrust/detail/device/cuda/detail/stable_radix_sort.h>` or any other implementation detail files -- these are internal files to thrust.  You should only include files that define the public interface.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  With thrust :: stable_sort_by_key and with a GTX-460 my sort time is about 6.2 seconds with 2^26 int numbers and keys.  Throughput is then 2*2^26/6.2 = 21.6 MElements/sec.  but when I run the sample radix sort -with 2^20 elements, it's showing a throughput of 199 MElements/sec.   Do you have any idea why I'm not getting that throughput.

Comment: Not sure, but that throughput definitely looks low.   Maybe try modifying the sample step by step to match your app's sort to see?  First change to the same data type, then change to _by_key, and then change to stable.  Might help you narrow down the specific issue.